# Dynamic Loading of Modules using Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, dynamic-import

In my project, I have multiple widgets (complex components) which are published as npm modules. (You can consider these widgets as react apps which I will then add in my orchestrator.)

I have a main project which may contain the above mentioned widgets. However I get this information at runtime depending on the user interaction.
To achieve this I have written the following code

```js
var x = "@test/Widget1"; // will get this string from server request / prop from parent component.


Component = React.lazy(()=> import(
    /* webpackInclude: / @test\/Widget1 / */
x));
```

However this gives me an error -> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@test/Widget1'.

If I try to hardcode the same string on my import statement, it works properly.

How can I solve the problem for importing it dynamically? (@test/Widget1 is installed and present ion node modules.)